# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint in my sql tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables in which user_id is defined as primary key `user_id` in table named `users`  and in another table named `updates` I'm declaring a foreign key references to `user_id`,this is my users table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`username` VARCHAR(45) ,
`password` VARCHAR(100) ,
`email` VARCHAR(45) ,
`friend_count` INT(11) ,
`profile_pic` VARCHAR(150),
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`));
```

My update table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `updates` (
`update_id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`update` VARCHAR(45),
`user_id_fk` VARCHAR(45),
`created` INT(11) ,
`ip` VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(user_id));
```

on adding foreign key it is giving error saying:

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

so help me out in this?

Comment: Both columns have to be the same type and size,in your case you have INT and VARCHAR

Answer (score 2):

You should have `users`.`user_id` with the same type and length of `updates`.`user_id_fk` :

```
CREATE TABLE `updates` (
`update_id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`update` VARCHAR(45),
`user_id_fk` INT(11),
`created` INT(11) ,
`ip` VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(user_id));
```